# F# - Which ORM to choose?

Tags: orm, f#

I've just started playing with F#, and was wondering whether there is any *recommended* ORM's out there, for F#.

In C# I used NHibernate, which seems to be quite hard and ugly to implement in F#. I've also thought about using plain old `System.Data.SqlClient`, but thats like going back to the stone age...

Any suggestions?

Comment: F# 3.0 will solve this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been using F# support for LINQ to SQL when working on [fssnip.net](http://fssnip.net). It is fine when you need to load, edit, insert entities and it is fine for writing simple queries. It has some nice aspects e.g. you can use *splicing* to compose parts of a query.

However, the current implementation of F# to LINQ translator doesn't handle complex queries (nested function calls, advanced grouping and joins), so I wrote a few stored procedures. These can be nicely called via generated LINQ objects, but you have to write some SQL.

Alternatively, if you wanted to use the old fashioned `SqlClient`, you could make it nicer by using the dynamic (`?`) operator. I wrote about this in [this blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-sql.aspx). For simple scenarios, this could be quite good technique, because it is very simple.

Comment: Inded your blog post about how to use `SqlClient` seems very nice... However it bothers me that I wont be able to work with Entities (POCOS) :( - Also after what I've read, then LINQ to SQL is a dieing ORM?

Comment: +1 for your dynamic implementation. Developers pursue ORMs because they want simplicity, which is unfortunately something few ORMs deliver.

Comment: I'll give LINQ to SQL a shot.. atleast until EF Code first is in release or NHibernate catches up.

Answer (score 6):

This may be missing the point (like if this is just for education or fun), but if you already know how to use an ORM in C#, why not just do it in C# as a library and then do the rest of the logic in F#?  One of the major selling points for .NET languages is interoperability.

Comment: +1. As you say, it may be of some educational benefit to start again with an F# ORM, but it is more pragmatic to re-use a C# library if you are already familiar with it. The support in F# for existing DLL's is very good - I've used it many times, and never had a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using LINQ to SQL via the F# PowerPack. I'm using manual mapping (ie. creating my datacontext by hand, creating my POCO classes as well as writing the XML file to define my database layout). It seems to work well in F# from what I've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Two options for interacting with databases using F# that might be of use are [FSharp.Data.SqlClient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) and [SQLProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/).